# Issue with rendering jQuery Mobile Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox, rendering

I am dynamically rendering the jQuery mobile Checkboxes inside a div tag. The issue that I am facing is that the first time the checkboxes are rendered they appear small, and when the second time the same page is loaded the checkboxes are properly rendered.

Below is the sample screenshot:

First Time Loading:
[image]

Second Time Loading:
[image]

Could any one please help with this issue of jQuery Mobile Checkboxes.

Below is my rendering code for the single checkbox:

```
      xmlArr += '<table id="technologyAreas" border="0" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background : #F0EFED">';
            xmlArr += '<tr><td style="width: 55%;background : #F0EFED">';
            xmlArr += '<fieldset id="techAreasCB" data-role="controlgroup" name="technologyAreasCheck" style="background : #F0EFED">';
            xmlArr += '<legend style="font-style: bold; font-size:16px;background : #F0EFED;width:100%"><label style="background : #F0EFED"><b>Areas<b>:</label></legend>';
     xmlArr += '<tr><td><div style="width:100%; background:#F0EFED;"><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="category'+item.categoryid+'" id="checkbox'+item.categoryid+'"  class="techAreasCheckBox" checked="checked"/></td><td class="myTD" style="padding-left:25px;"><label class="techAreasLabel" style="font-weight:100">'+item.categoryname+'</label></div></td></tr>';
 xmlArr += '</fieldset></td></tr></table>';
```

Is it possible to remove jQuery Mobile Checkbox CSS?

Comment: Ps: This happens even if the content is not rendered dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to override the jQuery CSS by using data-role="none" attribute.

The attribute that prevents styling is data-role="none"

```
<input type='checkbox' style='display:none' data-role="none" />
```

See the Jquery doc: "Preventing auto-initialization of form elements"

This worked for me :)